# Microsoft Office Word 2003 - Problem with saving File - Perhaps equation

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2003, equations

I have a Microsoft Word File (Version 2003) with 366 pages with a lot of formulas (Microsoft Equation 3.0). The Office Password Function is also used, for opening and changing. Now everytime I try to save the file I get the following Error "The disk is full trying to write to C:" and if you click this away a message saying, "To many files are open." appears.

The disk is appearently not full (checked in My Computer), and it's the only file that is open.

I guessed it has to do something with the big size of the document. (If I copy a part of it into a new document, ~20 pages, it saves without problems). Also the new Word Format (2007) makes no problems, but my client wants to use Word 2003. If I copy everything into a new document the same problem appears again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this, you have corrupted links within the document. This makes sense seeing as if you bring the page number down it works (due to you probably not including the pages with bad links).

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/224041

As the articles suggests, try going to `Edit > Select All` then pressing `F9`. This will force the document to update object/field links. You'll probably get an error in which case you'll be able to fix the broken link.

Comment: It didn't work out that time, had to separate the files.